# Pandas dataframe pivot not fitting in memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have a dataframe `df` with the following structure:

```
        val          newidx    Code
Idx                             
0       1.0      1220121127    706
1       1.0      1220121030    706
2       1.0      1620120122    565
```

It has 1000000 lines. 
In total we have 600 unique `Code` value and 200000 unique `newidx` values.

If I perform the following operation

```
df.pivot_table(values='val', index='newidx', columns='Code', aggfunc='max')
```

I get a `MemoryError` . but this sounds strange as the size of the resulting dataframe should be sustainable: 200000x600.

How much memory requires such operation? Is there a way to fix this memory error?

Comment: you have 120 million items. 4 fields, I'm not sure but I would say 32 bytes per row which approaches 4Gb. So do you run a 32-bit version of python or 64 bits?

Comment: 32-bits, on a computer with 4-gb of ram ..

Comment: it's really low spec for the problem you're having. There's a nasty workaround hack to perform if the answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

Try to see if this fits in your memory:

```
df.groupby(['newidx', 'Code'])['val'].max().unstack()
```

`pivot_table` is unfortunately very memory intensive as it may make multiple copies of data.

---

If the `groupby` does not work, you will have to split your DataFrame into smaller pieces. Try not to assign multiple times. For example, if reading from csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv').groupby(['newidx', 'Code'])['val'].max().unstack()
```

avoids multiple assignments.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a very similar problem when carrying out a merge between 4 dataframes recently.

What worked for me was disabling the index during the groupby, then merging.

if @Kartiks answer doesn't work, try this before chunking the DataFrame.

```
df.groupby(['newidx', 'Code'], as_index=False)['val'].max().unstack()
```