# Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

**1. Read Csv File ratings**

```
ratings = pd.read_csv('mls/ratings.csv', encoding='latin-1')
ratings.head(3)
```

[image]

**2. information**

```
user = ratings .userId.nunique()
fimId = ratings .movieId.nunique()
count_rating = len(ratings)
user, fimId, count_rating

(138493, 26744, 20000263)
```

**3. i want to create a Matrix on Rating**

```
ratings_matrix = ratings.pivot_table(index=['movieId'],columns['userId'],values='rating').reset_index(drop=True)
ratings_matrix.fillna( 0, inplace = True )
ratings_matrix.head(5)
```

**did I make a mistake/inconsistency ?**
and an error occurs

```
ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

There is a Forum that recommends 'Shrink the size of input for .pivot() function.' but I don't know the steps to Shrink yet.

I really appreciate all answers even if only the steps you know

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing actual data, but pandas has a very useful section on scaling up in data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html.  I would try 1) verify your pivot with smaller data 2) discarding unneeded data & use efficient data types, 3) use dask if necessary (they include the same `pivot_table` function, but operates on disk instead of in-memory)

Comment: Please show us your data to help us check why the `int32 overflow` is occuring

Comment: @anon01 I have updated the question information, Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: @Sagar I have updated the question information, Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: no images please.  Use df.to_dict() for exmaple.

Comment: @hubbakaghoyati Could you please share the link to the data (CSV File) so that I can play with it and maybe give you a solution to this. You can use [WeTransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/) and share the link here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Unstacked Data is **larger** than the `int32` range which can be handled by Pandas. This, being a *library limitation*, can be handled by **smartly dividing the data** into handleable groups

You can do this easily by the `groupby()` function by Pandas

---

Here's what I suggest:

- Group Your Data based on `userId` or `movieId`
- Access a particular group as required using the `get_group()`
- You can even check out all the groups created by the `groupby()` operation using the `groups` parameter
- You can store a particular group as a separate, smaller `DataFrame` if required

Here's how it can be done (I have taken `movieId` as a grouping parameter for the data in question):

```
>>> rating_groups = ratings.groupby('movieId')
>>> rating_groups.groups    # Returns a PrettyDict with the Group Identifiers as Keys and List of DataFrame Indices as its Value
{2: [0], 29: [1], 32: [2]}
```

You can now use `rating_groups.get_group(<Group Identifier>)` to get the required group as a DataFrame consisting all rows of the same movieId as mentioned by the Group Identifier

```
>>> rating_groups.get_group(2)
   userId  movieId  rating   timestamp
0       1        2     3.5  1112486027
```

If your individual group data is still very large, you can perform *multiple grouping* by providing the parameter to `groupby()` as a `list` of Column Identifiers. The Group Identifier will now be a `tuple` of lower-order identifiers

Here, I have performed Multiple Grouping with `movieId` and `userId` as the keys:

```
>>> multi_group = ratings.groupby(['movieId', 'userId'])
>>> multi_group.groups
{(2, 1): [0], (29, 1): [1], (32, 1): [2]}
```

You can now perform the `pivot_table()` on these group DataFrames

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `groupby()` as below :

`ratings_matrix = user_items.groupby(['user_id', 'movie_id'])['rating'].max().unstack()`

found from here : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648991/pandas-dataframe-pivot-not-fitting-in-memory)